# Access denied to Azure Active Directory and Users and Groups and some other blades in azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm very new user to Azure.

When navgating to Users and Groups or Azure Active Directory , I ferst see the page but after 2 seconds I get "Access Denied" and "You Do not have Access", "Looks like you don't have access to this content. To get access, please contact the owner."

My colleagues have same problem when using their company email connected azure accounts. But when using a private hotmail-linked Azure account there are no problems.

I want to use my company email account now, but this issue let us have trouble. Can anyone give some advice?

Thanks advance!

Comment: Are your private email account's directory and your company email's directory in same Directory?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT ，Yeah，they all in same directory，I saw your answer and I will try it，thank you for your reply.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your both accounts are in same Directory, this issue may caused by your Directory Role of your company email account has not enough Authority.

1. Go to subscription in Azure portal >Access control> Select your Account> Directory role, Check your Directory is whether User, Global administrator or Limited administrator
2. If your Directory role is not administrator, you can ask another Global administrator in this Directory to change your Directory role in subscription.

It may cost few minutes ,then you can re-login your company email account to check your Azure Active Directory.

Comment: Hi，@Wayne，I check it，my directory role of company email account is just user . I set it as global administrator using my hotmail account and it worked.

Comment: @Zora, I'm glad to hear that your issue has resolved.